# Is there a way to understand what install error codes actually mean?

Tags: android, kotlin, apk, updates, google-play-core

I'm trying out the in-app update feature and I'm getting a FAILED install status and a -100 install error code. Is there any way for me to know what may be causing this?

I implemented the flexible in-app update and I'm logging each step. Followed Android devs tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates#immediate_flow)

I'm generating an apk with a lower version code as the one in Google Play and signing using the same signing key.

```
2019-07-24 16:21:01 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install error : 0 
2019-07-24 16:21:01 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install status : 1 
2019-07-24 16:21:01 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install error : 0 
2019-07-24 16:21:01 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install status : 1 
2019-07-24 16:21:01 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install status : 1 
2019-07-24 16:21:01 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install error : 0 
2019-07-24 16:21:01 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install status : 2 
2019-07-24 16:21:01 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install error : 0 
2019-07-24 16:21:01 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install status : 2 
2019-07-24 16:21:01 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install error : 0 
2019-07-24 16:21:01 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install error : 0 
2019-07-24 16:21:01 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install status : 2 
2019-07-24 16:21:01 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install error : 0 
2019-07-24 16:21:01 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install status : 2 
2019-07-24 16:21:01 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install status : 2 
2019-07-24 16:21:01 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install error : 0 
2019-07-24 16:21:12 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install status : 2 
2019-07-24 16:21:12 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install error : 0 
2019-07-24 16:21:12 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install status : 2 
2019-07-24 16:21:12 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install error : 0 
2019-07-24 16:21:12 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install error : 0 
2019-07-24 16:21:12 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install status : 2 
2019-07-24 16:21:12 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install status : 11 
2019-07-24 16:21:12 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install error : 0 
2019-07-24 16:21:12 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | completeUpdate was called. 
2019-07-24 16:21:12 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install status : 3 
2019-07-24 16:21:12 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install error : 0 
2019-07-24 16:21:12 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-594849490]  [T# main]  | onPause 
2019-07-24 16:21:12 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install error : -100 
2019-07-24 16:21:12 +0100 InAppUpdates [String#-666477938]  [T# main]  | install status : 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Clear the PlayStore app Storage from the Android Settings App -
Settings -> Apps -> Play Store -> Storage -> clear data

and this error will disappear .. I don't what is the actual reason for this error .. and there no documentation that can guide you.

Comment: There is no need to "clear data", just "clear cache".

Answer (score 0):

You can find values for `InstallStatus` ((i.e) install status : %d) [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/install/model/InstallStatus) and the values for `InstallErrorCode` ((i.e) install error : %d) [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/install/model/InstallErrorCode).

#### InstallStatus

```
CANCELED
Constant Value: 6 (0x00000006)

DOWNLOADED
Constant Value: 11 (0x0000000b)

DOWNLOADING
Constant Value: 2 (0x00000002)

FAILED
Constant Value: 5 (0x00000005)

INSTALLED
Constant Value: 4 (0x00000004)

INSTALLING
Constant Value: 3 (0x00000003)

PENDING
Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)

REQUIRES_UI_INTENT
To perform the installation, a Play Store UI flow needs to be started.
Constant Value: 10 (0x0000000a)

UNKNOWN
Constant Value: 0 (0x00000000)
```

#### InstallErrorCode

```
ERROR_API_NOT_AVAILABLE
The API is not available on this device.
Constant Value: -3 (0xfffffffd)

ERROR_DOWNLOAD_NOT_PRESENT
The install/update has not been (fully) downloaded yet.
Constant Value: -7 (0xfffffff9)

ERROR_INSTALL_IN_PROGRESS
The install is already in progress and there is no UI flow to resume.
Constant Value: -8 (0xfffffff8)

ERROR_INSTALL_NOT_ALLOWED
The download/install is not allowed, due to the current device state (e.g. low battery, low disk space, ...).
Constant Value: -6 (0xfffffffa)

ERROR_INSTALL_UNAVAILABLE
The install is unavailable to this user or device.
Constant Value: -5 (0xfffffffb)

ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR
An internal error happened in the Play Store.
Constant Value: -100 (0xffffff9c)

ERROR_INVALID_REQUEST
The request that was sent by the app is malformed.
Constant Value: -4 (0xfffffffc)

ERROR_UNKNOWN
An unknown error occurred.
Constant Value: -2 (0xfffffffe)

NO_ERROR
No error occurred; all types of update flow are allowed.
Constant Value: 0 (0x00000000)

NO_ERROR_PARTIALLY_ALLOWED
No error occurred; only some types of update flow are allowed, while others are forbidden.
Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)
```

Comment: I know what the codes mean, I'm looking for what may be the reason of the ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR which I can't seem to find anywhere or understand.

Comment: What does the malformed request means here? The request gets sent via the Play Core library itself. "ERROR_INVALID_REQUEST: The request that was sent by the app is malformed."

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with this issue for a day or so now and the issue was that my apk wasn't signed and verified. I believe that when you run an unverified apk AppUpdateManager will check for an available update on the PlayStore, however during the installation process it will fail when it realizes that its replacing an unverified apk with a verified one.