# How to solve install status code -100 while working with In-App update in Android?

Tags: android, in-app-update

I'm working with In-App update from here: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates

I have successfully implemented it in my app. My app is already in playstore: 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tekitsolution.remindly

for Testing this implementation, I decreased version in my project and I implemented in Splash Activity.

So, I got the update screen, I click on update and it started downloading. After completing the download, it is again coming same page to download and `installErrorCode` is getting -100 which means An internal error happened in the Play Store. ([Is there a way to understand what install error codes actually mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57186822/is-there-a-way-to-understand-what-install-error-codes-actually-mean))

```
Flow from update screen:
I printed logs for `state.installStatus()`
PENDING = 1;
DOWNLOADING = 2;
DOWNLOADED = 11;
INSTALLING = 3;
```

then instead of this (INSTALLED = 4), I'm getting FAILED = 5 with state.installErrorCode -100

Code:

```
private InstallStateUpdatedListener installStateUpdatedListener = new
                        InstallStateUpdatedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onStateUpdate(InstallState state) {
                                showLog("In-App: " + state.installStatus());
                                showLog("installErrorCode " + state.installErrorCode());
                                if (state.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED) {
                                    popupSnackbarForCompleteUpdate();
                                } else if (state.installStatus() == InstallStatus.INSTALLED) {
                                    if (mAppUpdateManager != null) {
                                        showLog("In-App: unregisterListener");
                                        mAppUpdateManager.unregisterListener(installStateUpdatedListener);}

                                }
                            }
                        };
```

Note: I tried with different devices also.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55939853/how-to-work-with-androids-in-app-update-api)

Comment: from what I have observed, most of time it comes when device is low on storage

Comment: @Piyush Arey, I tried na

Comment: @Gautam I can tell you that there is no issue from storage side

Comment: Can you get a callback for update status?

Comment: @ViralPatel I'm checking onStateUpdate and onActivityResult also

Comment: I implement In-App Update in my app its working proper update app, but I use same code on my another 5-6 app but it's not updated, I think its google bug

Comment: is this solved? what the status?