# Install Error(-100) in Google Play Core in app update

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-update, google-play-core

We implemented some time ago In App Updates using Google Play Core library, and recently (started on September 8th) to shown on our Crashlytics lots of Install Error (-100) crashes.
Not sure if Google Play rollout something on that day, but even after we update the library to version 1.8.0 (before it was 1.7.3), the crashes continue reaching up to 7% of our daily active users.
Following the stacktrace of the crash:

```
Caused by com.google.android.play.core.install.InstallException: Install Error(-100): An internal error happened in the Play Store. (https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/install/model/InstallErrorCode#ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR)
   at com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.o.a(o.java:6)
   at com.google.android.play.core.internal.o.a(o.java:28)
   at com.google.android.play.core.internal.j.onTransact(j.java:20)
   at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1056)
   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1029)
```

The question is what is this error? Internal Error seems to be a generic one, which doesn't say much about how can I fix it.

It seems to be a duplicated of this one, but as there is no answer to it I'm asking again.
[How to solve install status code -100 while working with In-App update in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58517654/how-to-solve-install-status-code-100-while-working-with-in-app-update-in-androi)

Comment: Seems like bugs. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192708&template=840533

Answer (score -1):

I have solution!

For testing you app you mast to upload two versions of apk to the [Enternal app sharing](https://play.google.com/console/internal-app-sharing).

First version - for example version code 1, the second version - version code 2.

Nexn step - You need to get the first app link from enternal app storage and follow this link, install this apk on your smartphone.

Next - follow on link of the second app, but dont press any button on opened screen, just close market screen. 3. Step three - open the first app and try to update by following your update steps logic in your app.